# Python interpreter closes without accepting input, program works correctly in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code accepts input and produces the correct output when run in IDLE. When run by right-clicking and selecting Open With > Python, the window opens and closes immediately without accepting input. I think the problem is caused by repeatedly opening and closing the 'worldserieswinners.txt' file but I am unsure of how to implement this differently, or why this would cause the program to close without accepting input if it works correctly in IDLE.

```
def main():
    team_set = set()
    text_file = open('worldserieswinners.txt', 'r')
    for team in text_file:
        team = team.rstrip('\n')
        team_set.update([team])
    print(team_set)
    text_file.close()    
   
    empty_wins_dict = {team : 0 for team in team_set}
    wins_dict = wins_count(empty_wins_dict)
    empty_year_dict = {year: '' for year in range(1903, 2010)}
    year_dict = years_dict(empty_year_dict)
    display_values(year_dict, wins_dict)

def display_values(dict_1, dict_2):  
    try:
        search_1 = int(input('Enter a year from 1903 - 2009 to see the World Series Winner: '))
        print(f'The winner of the {search_1} World Series was {dict_1[search_1]}.')
      
    except KeyError:
        while search_1 < 1903 or search_1 > 2009:
            search_1 = int(input('Invalid year. Please enter a year from 1903 - 2009: '))
        print(f'The winner of the {search_1} World Series was {dict_1[search_1]}.')
    try:
        search_2 = input('Enter team name to see how many times they have won the World Series: ')
        print(f'The {search_2} have {dict_2[search_2]} wins.')
    except KeyError:
        while search_2 not in dict_2:
            search_2 = input('That team has never won the World Series, or it was not ' +
                             'a valid team name. Please enter another name, making sure to capitalize properly: ')
        print(f'The {search_2} have {dict_2[search_2]} wins.')

def wins_count(dict_name):
    text_file = open('worldserieswinners.txt', 'r')
    for line in text_file:
        team = line.rstrip('\n')
        dict_name[team] += 1
    text_file.close()
    return dict_name

def years_dict(dict_name):
    text_file = open('worldserieswinners.txt', 'r')
    year = 1903
    for line in text_file:
        team = line.rstrip('\n')
     
        dict_name[year] += team
        year += 1
    text_file.close()
    return dict_name
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The LIKELY problem is that the script cannot find the file.  Remember that `open` looks in whatever the current directory is.  It doesn't look in the same folder as the script.  You can get the folder the script is in using `os.abspath(os.dirname(__file__))`.  And yes, you should read the text file in once at the beginning and store it in a list or dictionary, so you can reuse it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the advice and for editing my question to make it more readable.